# HTML Tag ClientID in a .NET Project

Tags: .net, asp.net

If I want to manipulate an HTML tag's properties on the server within an aspx page based on a master page i.e.

```
<a href="#" runat="server" ID="myLink">My Link</a>
```

For example to give the link a different class depending on the current page i.e.

```
if (Path.GetFileName(Request.PhysicalPath) == "MyPage")
{
myLink.Attributes.Add("class","active");
}
```

.NET changes the ID property of the link to something like

```
<a href="#" ID="ct100-foo-myLink">My Link</a>
```

Is there any way of stopping this from happening and keeping the original ID?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way.

It shows the actual control tree, which is in this case masterpage-content-control.

However if you add an ID to the masterpage (this.ID = "whatever") then you will see "whatever" instead of ctl00 (which means control index 0).

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible directly. You could make a new control that inherits the link and override its ClientID to return directly the ID. But this seems to be overkill. You can simply use HTML markup and use <%# GetClass() %> to add the class when you need it.

Regarding the usage of ClientID for Javascript:

```
<a ID="myLink" runat="server">....


var ctrl = document.getElementById('<%# myLink.ClientID %>');
```

Of course you need a DataBind somewhere in the code.

Comment: THanks i'll see if I can get this solution going. Trying to be as little "hacky" as possible

Comment: This surely isn't "hacky" :) It is actually the purpose of the ClientID property.

Comment: this is the way to do it if you must make it a runat server control. but why do that, why not just use a regular a tag and just set the class to a method call using a render block instead

Comment: @ChanChan - of course that's also possible. It depends from case to case. In the general case it's still useful to know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered an easy way to do it if you are using jQuery.

```
var mangled_name = $("[id$=original_name]").attr("id");
```

So if you have a server control like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server" />
```

You can get the mangled name in your jQuery/Javascript with:

```
var start_date_id = $("[id$=txtStartDate]").attr("id");
```

Since it is a string, you can also use it "inline" instead of assigning it, e.g. concatenating it with other elements for selectors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

However, you probably want to keep the original name so that you can manipulate the control with javascript.... if that's the case, you should look into ClientID; it will return the assigned ID at runtime.

**EDIT:**

It looks like there is a way to do it, but with some work... take a look at [ASP.NET Controls - Improving automatic ID generation : Architectural Changes ( Part 3)](http://weblogs.asp.net/nunogomes/archive/2008/06/04/asp-net-controls-improving-automatic-id-generation-architectural-changes-part-3.aspx)

I didn't read the full post, but it looks like he created his own container and own naming provider.  I think that if you wanted to leave your control's name untouched, you would just return the name back in

```
public abstract string SetControlID(string name, System.Web.UI.Control control);
```

Answer (score 0):

I never figured out how to prevent .NET from doing this, but what I did start doing was placing asp:Literals and using c# to add a WebControl to them. If you write a WebControl you can set various properties without it getting .NET's unique ID.
For instance:

```
<asp:Literal ID="myLink" />
```

...

```
WebControl a = new WebControl(HtmlTextWriterTag.A);
a.CssClass = "active";
a.Attributes["href"] = "#";
Literal text = new Literal();
text.Text = "click here";
a.Controls.Add(text);
myLink.Controls.Add(a);
```

Which will result in the following html:

```
<a href="#" class="active">click here</a>
```

Overall, a pretty dirty solution, but I didn't know what else to do at the time and I had a deadline to meet. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yep exactly, we will need to persist the original ID for JavaScript and CSS reasons. I noticed the ClientId property but it's read only and can't be assigned, so i'm not sure how I would use it?

Answer (score 0):

This **blog post** could be helpful:
[Remove Name Mangling from ASP.Net Master Pages (get your ID back!)](http://gathadams.com/2008/08/18/remove-name-mangling-from-aspnet-master-pages-get-your-id-back/)

The solution in the post overwrites the `.getElementById` method, allowing you to search for the element just using the normal ID. Maybe you can adapt it to your needings.

**Disclaimer:** That ASP.NET behaviour is by design and it is good that way, even for HTML Server Controls like the control in your example. Server-ID and Client-ID are two very different things, which should not be mixed. Using Master Pages or User Controls you could end with identical Client-IDs if there wasn't that mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a standard a tag, and use render blocks to modify it, and then you have its behavior locked in on client.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET 4 has property *ClientIDMode* that controls ClientID rendering.

Also, there is a [trick how to disable ClientID rendering for any non-postback control](http://clientidless.codeplex.com/) (ASP.NET 2.0+).