# How do I bind a Javascript event handler to the Ajax Control Toolkit combobox when textbox changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, jquery-events, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I need a combobox for an ASP.NET project, so I decided to use the Ajax Control Toolkit combobox (http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx).

I don't want to use the postback as I don't want the page reloaded, but I need to know when the text in the textbox is changed so I can call out to the server to persist the new list item.

I am curious how I bind an `onchange` or `onblur` event to the input box that this combobox uses.

This is my asp.net page:

```
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="cc1" %>

<cc1:ComboBox ID="PlantDropDown" runat="server" OnInit="PlantDropDown_Init" DropDownStyle="DropDown" 
             AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" 
            ItemInsertLocation="OrdinalText" AutoPostBack="false">


                </cc1:ComboBox>
```

Update: I tried using the suggestion and I get this error:

> $find("PlantDropDown") is null
> [Break on this error]
> $find('PlantDropDown').add_propertyChanged(function(sender, e) {\r\n

I am using jQuery for the Javascript side, btw, in case that helps.

Final Update:
I got it to work thanks to help from crescentfresh, and at the end I have this in my .aspx file:

```
<input type="hidden" id="PlantDropDownID" value="<%= PlantDropDown.ClientID %>" />
```

And this is in my javascript file, since I don't push javascript in my .aspx file:

```
elem = document.getElementById('PlantDropDownID');
$find(elem.value).add_propertyChanged(function(sender, e) {
    if (e.get_propertyName() == 'selectedIndex') {
        var newValue = sender.get_textBoxControl().value;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you are supposed to bind to the `"propertyChanged"` event and check for changes to the `"selectedIndex"` property:

```
$find('PlantDropDown').add_propertyChanged(function(sender, e) {
    if (e.get_propertyName() == 'selectedIndex') {
        var newValue = sender.get_textBoxControl().value;

        // persist selected value here...
    }
})
```

with the usual caveat about [.NET control ids in the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114339/html-tag-clientid-in-a-net-project).

The api is not easy, that's for sure. There is no `.get_value()` method for example, which would be nice instead of having to go through the embedded textbox control.

**Edit**:

> $find("PlantDropDown") is null

Make sure you are using the **correct id**. See [.NET control ids in the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114339/html-tag-clientid-in-a-net-project). To get a reference you may have to do:

```
$find('<%= PlantDropDown.ClientID %>')
```

> I am using jQuery for the javascript side

That holds no bearing.

Comment: Thank you, I am testing it out, hopefully I will know how it works soon.

Comment: +1 - You were unbelievably helpful as I had no idea how to approach this.

Comment: My problem is that `document.getElementById('..properid name')` has no method called `add_propertyChanged`. Rather it eventually gets a `control` property which does have `add_propertyChanged`. Anyone know how I can be notified when `control` is attached?

Comment: @Gezim: use `$find`, not `document.getElementById`. The former is Microsoft's framework, the latter is the W3C DOM api.

Comment: @CrescentFresh, thanks for your response. I tried using $find() but it's returning a null. I did use use it as such `$find('<%= controlaname.ClientID %>')`. I'm guessing the control isn't constructed yet...but not sure.

Comment: Actually, yeah, that turned out to be the issue. Adding a `setTimeout()` call with a 1 second wait works. Not sure if there's a better solution.

Comment: @Gezim: David Hall's answer addresses exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

I found the I could not get the provided answer to work unless I wrapped it in a function as shown below. Not sure why that is but hopefully it saves someone else some pain.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    Sys.Application.add_load(initializePage);

    function initializePage() {
        $find('PlantDropDown').add_propertyChanged(function(sender, e) {    
        if (e.get_propertyName() == 'selectedIndex') {        
        var newValue = sender.get_textBoxControl().value;        
        // persist selected value here...    
        }})
    }

</script>
```

Comment: You cannot interact with a control until it has been initialized (eg you cannot call `add_propertyChanged` on a control unless the control actually exists). A control does not exist until the initialization phase of the ASP.NET AJAX framework is complete. So what you have done is exactly right. See http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/AJAXClientEvents.aspx for the full lowdown.

Comment: By the way if you would like to get the selectedIndex value as opposed to the text of the selected item, use `sender.get_hiddenFieldControl().value` instead of `sender.get_textBoxControl().value`. The AJAX Combobox uses a textbox, unorderedlist, and hidden field all together to comrise the control.